# cannot upgrade to tor unstable version

Tags: relays

i run a tor relay on a raspberry pi3. all is ok so far but when i try to upgrade tor 0.4.2.7 to the latest unstable version it says something like: N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org buster InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Tor no longer provides 32-bit armhf versions of tor. You will either need to upgrade your OS to a 64-bit version, build tor from source, or check if Debian provides a compatible 32-bit armhf build. See: https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2020-May/045583.html